# Find general solution of first order non-linear in a transcendental function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, transcendental-equations

I have the function $$\frac{dV}{dT}=1-V^2$$

Just looking to see if my working is okay.

$$dV=1-V^2dT$$
$$\frac{1}{1-V^2}dV=dT$$

Integrate

$$\int{}\frac{1}{1-V^2}dV=\int{}dT$$
Let $V=\tanh(x)$

$\frac{dV}{dx}=sech^2(x)$

$dV=sech^2(x)dx$

$$\int{}\frac{1}{1-\tanh^2(x)}sech^2(x)dx=\int{}dT$$

$1-tanh^2(x)=sech^2(x)$
$$\int{}\frac{1}{sech^2(x)}sech^2(x)dx=\int{}dT$$
$$\int{}\frac{sech^2(x)}{sech^2(x)}dx=\int{}dT$$
$$\int{}\ dx=\int{}\ dT$$
$$x=\int{}dT$$
$V=\tanh(x)$ so take $\tanh^{-1}$ of both sides to find x
$$\tanh^{-1}(V)=x$$
$$\tanh^{-1}(V)=\int{}dT$$
$$=T+C$$
Take tanh of both side
$$V=\tanh(T+C)$$

Therefore the general solution of $\frac{dV}{dT}=1-V^2$ is $V=\tanh(T+C)$

It is then asking for the particular solution of this for when t=0, v=0 for V is a function of T. I have no idea what they mean.

Comment: To check your answer substitute back in the differential equation.

Comment: Anyone? I'm pretty sure I have the general solution okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite
$$
\begin{align}
\int{}\frac{1}{1-V^2}dV&=\frac{1}{2}\int{}\left(\frac{1}{1-V}+\frac{1}{1+V}\right)dV\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{1}{1-V}\ dV+\int\frac{1}{1+V}\ dV\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1-V)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+V)+C\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+V}{1-V}\right)+C
\end{align}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
T&=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+V}{1-V}\right)+C\\
\ln\left(\frac{1+V}{1-V}\right)&=2(T-C)\\
\frac{1+V}{1-V}&=e^{2(T-C)}\\
\frac{1+V}{1-V}&=Ke^{2T}\quad\Rightarrow\quad K=e^{-2C}\\
1+V&=Ke^{2T}-Ke^{2T}V\\
V+Ke^{2T}V&=Ke^{2T}-1\\
(1+Ke^{2T})V&=Ke^{2T}-1\\
V&=\frac{Ke^{2T}-1}{Ke^{2T}+1}.
\end{align}
$$
**Note that, your solution is also correct**.

Now, plugging in the initial condition where $V=0$ when $T=0$. The purpose of the initial condition is to obtain the value of $K$, in your case $C$.
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{Ke^{2(0)}-1}{Ke^{2(0)}+1}\\
0&=\frac{K-1}{K+1}\\
K-1&=0\\
K&=1
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
V(T)=\frac{e^{2T}-1}{e^{2T}+1}.
$$

Comment: In your case, you will obtain $C=0$.